# Restoring purchases on multiple Android devices

Tags: android, cordova, in-app-purchase

I have an issue with restoring purchases.

The case is this:
I have a test Google account which I am signed in with on two different devices. I run the same app on both and make an in-app purchase on device #1. I get the product and everything is fine. On device #2 I then do restore purchases. I expect to get my newly purchased in-app product which I bought from device #1, but instead I get an empty list. Why? If I then try to buy the same product on device #2 it gives me "You already own this item.".

This scenario is also the same if I buy the item on device #2 first instead. Also, clearing data and restoring purchases on the device where the item was originally bought on works fine.

Shouldn't I be able to restore purchases on several devices with the same account? Is it because I'm in test mode, or what could be the problem?

I'm using cordova-plugin-inapppurchase.

Thank you very much!

/Klarre

Comment: Yes, a consumable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be caused by the Google Play app/service caching the purchases response for a while. I don't know for how long, but if you clear the cache of Google Play (not your app) and/or the stored data of it, then it will retrieve the up-to-date list.